# When the page is loaded completely, Disappear Loading

Tags: jquery

I have many pages of pictures and text.
I want to hide/remove the "Loading page" only when the page is loaded completely (that is all pictures and text) through ajax.

Here is my code :

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="./ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#txt").ajaxSend(function() {
            $("#wait").css("display", "block");
        });
        $("#txt").ajaxComplete(function() {
            $("#wait").css("display", "none");
        });
        $("button").click(function() {
            $("#txt").load("randomPage.html", function() { //randomPage.html have pics and text
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="txt"></div>
<img src="loader.gif" alt="" id="wait" style="display: none">
<button>click me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your response.

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer on how you intend the page to work? How is the loading page displayed? Popup? JS overlay? How does the loading page relate to the page with the content? How is the loading function called?

Comment: Are you saying that the problem begins when `randomPage.html` is done loading? Then it won't have anything to do with the code you posted here, or would it?

Comment: i want when randomPage.html called, loader.gif ==> display : block
&
when randomPage.html completely loaded, display : none,
but my code have problem, because not all images are loaded
Disappear Loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that text will show up instantly and for the images you can count how many images there are in the page and set the counter in load event for those images, and hide loader when they all appear.

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("#wait").css("display", "block");
    $.get('randomPage.html', function(page) {
       var m = page.match(/<img /g);
       if (m) {
         var counter = 0;
         $("#txt").html(page).find('img').load(function() {
             counter++;
             if (counter == m.length) {
                $("#wait").css("display", "none");
             }
       } else {
         $("#txt").html(page);
         $("#wait").css("display", "none");
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try using the direct function $.ajax.

```
//Show the Loader
$.ajax({
  url:"<<your request url>>",
  success:function(data){
   //Removing the loader    
  }
});
```